# Tomcat 7.0 server starting issue

Tags: apache, tomcat

### Tomcat v7.0 server at localhost has encountered a problem ##Hi I am getting Tomcat v 7.0 server at localhost has encountered a problem-could not publish server configuration: null I changed working directories also I did a lot but I am getting the same error for three days please anyone help me thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I once had similar problem and it was caused by missing reference to web.xml in my Eclipse project.

P.S. If you want to receive more relevant answers try formulating your question better, with more details, when this error ocured and how... Write down steps you are making until exception shows etc., exception stack trace...